# ARKit make an SCNLight point ahead where the camera is looking?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

So I have access to the `sceneView.pointOfView`and I want to make the AR experience feel like I am shining a flash light straight in front of my to objects I look at become lit as I point at them.

I tried to create a spotlight like this:

```
let spotLight = SCNLight()
spotLight.type = .spot
spotLight.spotInnerAngle = 60
spotLight.spotOuterAngle = 60
let spotNode = SCNNode()
spotNode.light = spotLight
spotNode.position = position
```

I then thought that adding the light to the pointOfView node would make it so the light would move with the camera, meaning it would always shine light ahead...

```
sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(spotLight)
```

this is not working, the objects appear black, no light.

What am I doing wrong? I want to make it so the light points at what I look at through the AR experience, just as if I was holding a flashlight and I was shining light straight ahead....

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for a virtual flashlight that realistically illuminates the real-world scene in the camera feed? That's a very tall order.

You're basically talking about projection-mapping a light cone onto every real-world surface that's visible, which requires detecting and modeling those surfaces, which is a whole lot more than the horizontal plane detection ARKit does.

(If you want to not-realistically illuminate the real-world scene, all you need to do is place a semi-transparent white circle in the middle of the view. Maybe get fancy with blend modes. For a tiny bit more realistic, vary the size of, or the 3D distance to, your circle based on [hit-testing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arhittestresult) the center of your view against the AR scene.)

---

Do you want a virtual flashlight that illuminates the virtual objects you've placed in AR? That's easily doable. And in fact, your code is most of the way to doing that. The likely problems:

```
spotNode.position = position
```

Your snippet above doesn't say where you're getting this position. If you want the spotlight node attached to the camera, it should be a zero vector. That is, you want it to have a neutral position in the local space of the camera node. Setting this vector to non-zero would offset your light source from the camera position by a constant displacement (possibly so much that it results in the light not doing anything useful in your scene).

```
sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(spotLight)
```

Depending on when this code runs, `sceneView.pointOfView` may be nil, and so you're not actually executing the `addChildNode` call. Check to make sure the camera node exists before adding a child to it. (I tried adding this code to the sample code from the [ARKit WWDC17 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/) — if you put it in their `ARSCNView.setup()` function, you should see any virtual objects you place getting completely whited out by a bright spotlight.)

By the way, you don't necessarily need to add a child node to the `pointOfView` node to hold a light — the `pointOfView` node can have both a camera and a light attached.

Comment: I ended up attaching my spot light to the pointOfView like you mentioned at the end. That allowed me to achieve what I wanted. Thank you.